# If $P(A)=0.7 , P(B)=0.6 \text{ and } P(A'\cap B)=0.25$. Deduce $P(A\cup B)=?$

Tags: probability, statistics

Can anyone help me with this pls. The questions is $P(A)=0.7 , P(B)=0.6 \text{ and } P(A'\cap B)=0.25$. Deduce $P(A\cup B)=?$

A' is A complementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the inclusion-exclusion principle, i.e., 
$$
P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)=0.7 + 0.6 - P(A\cap B).
$$
Now, note that 
$$
0.25 = P(B \cap \bar{A})= P(B) - P(B \cap A) = 0.6 - P(B \cap A),  
$$
thus
$$
P(B \cap A) = 0.35.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, its the right answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

From Inclusion-Exclusion,$$\begin{align}P(A\cup B)&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\&=P(A)+P(B)-(P(B)-P(A'\cap B))
\\&=P(A)+P(A'\cap B)\\&=0.7+0.25\\&=0.95\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, its the right answer. :)